# Cv2.error : (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to segment images based on their label tag as helmet, non-helmet or unprocessed images for my project. But there is error saying image object is null. I have already made a secondary script where I processed over the same image which is working.I don't know why but it seems opencv library is unable to read one particular image. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
import requests
import shutil
import json
import sys
import os
import cv2
x=0
lis=[]
s=""
def batwara(filename,data):
    print("unproccesed/"+filename[6:])
    print(data)

    image = cv2.imread(filename)
    if image is None:
        print("NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN")
        return
    color = (255, 0, 0)
    thickness = 2
    totfaces = data['annotation']
    if totfaces is None:
        cv2.imwrite("unproccesed/"+filename[6:],image)
        return

    x=0
    for face in totfaces:
        x=x+1
        new_file=str(x)+filename[9:]
        print(new_file)
        label= face['label']
        print ("label=============",label)
        wid=face['imageWidth']
        hei=face['imageHeight']

        x1=int(face['points'][0]['x']*wid)
        y1=int(face['points'][0]['y']*hei)
        x2=int(face['points'][1]['x']*wid)
        y2=int(face['points'][1]['y']*hei)

        #print (x1,y1,x2,y2,wid,hei)
        start_point = (x1, y1)
        end_point = (x2, y2)
        crop_img = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        if len(label)==0:
            new_file= "unidentified/img"+new_file
            cv2.imwrite(new_file,crop_img)
        elif label[0] == "Without Helmet":
            new_file= "non_helmet/img"+new_file
            cv2.imwrite(new_file,crop_img)
        elif label[0] == "With Helmet":
            new_file= "helmet/img"+new_file
            cv2.imwrite(new_file,crop_img)






with open('/home/oem/Downloads/Bikers Wearing Helmet Or Not.json') as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        s=s+c
        if c=='{' or c=='[':
            lis.append(c)
        if c==']'or c=='}':
                lis.pop()
                if len(lis)==0:
                    x=x+1
                    #print(filename)
                    #print(s)
                    data = json.loads(s)
                    filen,ex= os.path.splitext(data['content'])

                    filename= "image/img"+str(x)+ex
                    #print(data)
                    #print (data['content'])
                    # This is the image url.
                    image_url = data['content']
                    # Open the url image, set stream to True, this will return the stream content.
                    resp = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
                    # Open a local file with wb ( write binary ) permission.
                    local_file = open(filename, 'wb')
                    # Set decode_content value to True, otherwise the downloaded image file's size will be zero.
                    resp.raw.decode_content = True
                    # Copy the response stream raw data to local image file.
                    shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, local_file)
                    # Remove the image url response object.
                    del resp

                    if ex!=".png":
                        batwara(filename,data)
                    s=""


        if not c:
            print ("End of file")
            print(x)
            break
```

The error displayed on the terminal is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app2.py", line 91, in <module>
    batwara(filename,data)
  File "app2.py", line 46, in batwara
    cv2.imwrite(new_file,crop_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

Comment: Did you make sure that your crop is not empty? I.e. is it possible that `x1 == x2` or `y1 == y2`?

Comment: Thats not the case as the values are generated only when a face is found in an image.

Comment: What is the shape of the crop_img that fails saving?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I just now sorted out that y1==y2 so thats why crop_img was null. And shape of crop_img is (0,4,3)

Comment: Can you mark the answer as the answer then please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `x1 == x2` or `y1 == y2`